# Multiply two pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame, df1, that looks like:

```
CustomerID  CustomerValue CustomerValue2 
15          10            2
16          10            3
18          3             3
```

I have a second PySpark DataFrame, df2

```
 CustomerID  CustomerValue 
 15          2          
 16          3           
 18          4
```

I want to multiply all the columns of df1(I have more than two columns)
with the value of df2 join on customer ID. So i want to have something like that

```
 CustomerID     CosineCustVal CosineCustVal
 15             20            4
 16             30            9
 18             12            9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you join them, you can run a for loop on the columns of df1:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_joined = df1.join(df2, df1.CustomerID == df2.CustomerID)
for col_name in df_joined.columns:
    if col_name != 'CustomerValue':
        df_joined = df_joined.withColumn(col_name, F.column(col_name) * F.column('CustomerValue'))
```

Based on [this](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/performing-operations-on-multiple-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-36e97896c378) article, spark will create a smart plan even though the for loop would suggest otherwise (remember that spark only starts the calculations once you call an `action`, until that you just assign `transformations`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations).

Comment: Happy to hear :)